# Rails formatting logs to use with aws-logs and CloudWatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-5

AWS has this very cool log collection tool using `aws-logs`

However, I do not understand how I can format my log / configure the tool to be smarter and regroup the same error message. Right now AWS shows one message per line (because every line is timestamped)

[image]

My current log configuration indeed captures one new log entry per message. How can I go around it

```
[rails/production.log]
file = /var/www/xxx/shared/log/production.log
log_group_name = /rails/production.log
log_stream_name = {instance_id}
time_zone = LOCAL
datetime_format = %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
```

Comment: Did you check this blog https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudwatch-log-service/

Comment: I believe this is exactly the tutorial I followed. But it doesn't deal with long messages that span several times but should be regrouped under the same log event does it ?

Comment: I don't think regrouping will work from aws-log side you have to process the collected logs for achieving your use case

Answer (score 1):

I actually partly solved the problem using `lograge` and JSON output which is parsed correctly by Amazon and lets your regroup most requests correctly.

However I still have some problems with errors, which are not outputted the same way, and still generate one line per call stack trace on awslogs

EDIT : We are now using a Rails API and regular exceptions thrown during JSON requests are rescued with a json:api error handler renderer. Furthermore, we are using Rollbar to log actual errors, so it becomes irrelevant to have the full error log

In our API::ApplicationController

```rb
# We don't want error reports for those errors
RESCUABLE_ERRORS = [
  ActionController::ParameterMissing,
  ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError,
  StrongerParameters::InvalidParameter,
  Mongoid::Errors::Validations,
  Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound
]

# Note that in tests, we want to actually do not want to rescue non-Runtime exceptions straight away because most likely this indicates a real bug that you should fix, but in production we want to rescue any error so the frontend does not get the default HTML response but a JSON:api error
rescue_from(Rails.env.test? ? RuntimeError : Exception) do |e|
  handle_exception(e)
  notify_exception(e, 'Rescued from API controller - Rendering JSONAPI Error')
end

rescue_from(*RESCUABLE_ERRORS) do |e|
  handle_exception(e)
end
```

In our controllers that inherit API::ApplicationController, we add as many lines of `rescue_from` depending whether we want to report the exception as an error (`notify_exception`) or just convert to a JSON payload (`handle_exception`)

```rb
rescue_from(SPECIFIC_ERROR_CLASS) do |exception|
  handle_exception(exception) # will render a json:api error payload
  # notify_exception(exception) # Optional : ExceptionNotifier to broadcast the error to email/Rollbar, etc. if this error should not happen.
end
```